# How can I get 1280x720 resolution support in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to know how to add support for 1280x720 resolution in virtual-box with out using **Vboxmanage**.
 Is there any way I can patch the virtual-box VESA BIOS at start-up so that it supports this resolution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the modeline information

   ```
   gtf 1280 720 60
   ```

   eg:

   ```
   # 1280x720 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 44.76 kHz; pclk: 74.48 MHz
   Modeline "1280x720_60.00"  74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746  -HSync +Vsync
   ```
2. Get the output device

   ```
   xrandr | grep "\sconnected"
   ```

   eg:

   ```
   VGA-0 connected ...
   ```
3. Create a new mode

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"  74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746
   xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x720_60.00
   ```
4. Set the new mode

   ```
   xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x720_60.00
   ```

Finally you need a script for that, because this must be done every time you start VirtualBox.

Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"  74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x720_60.00
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x720_60.00
```

And start the script during the system start, eg in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add add the line

```
display-setup-script=<path_to_script>/<script_name>
```

If you need a more generic version, give me a ping.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the Guest Additions, you can use custom resolutions. And it should automatically resize if you change the GUI size too.

VBoxManage edits a config file so you can do it manually if you want. "virtualbox.xml" and "machine.xml" where machine is your instance. The latter holds screen resolutions.

Editing those files manually should be avoided. I would 1st try the guest additions, then vboxmanage and then manual. The latter can kill your VBox instance (so do make a backup).

The VBoxManage command to set a custom resolution is:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "<VM name>" "CustomVideoMode1" "1280x720x32"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I am trying to create a VMDK image in which i want to enable support for 1280x720 resolution by default with out using VBoxManage command.

Comment: @newuser a.b's method works but needs to be executed every time when starting the istance.